# Will my image be of ok quality when printed on a blanket

Tags: image-quality

My original image taken on my mothers new canon is 4650 x 5829. I am looking to print this image on a fleece blanket 60x80 in size, to give to my father but when i input it into the computer it tells me poor quality image of 72 dpi. Will this image be of good quality to print to give to my father or should i find another method?
Please help!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DPI is not a quality metric of your image. Its purely a conversion factor. It can be used as a way to do rough, estimates of visual quality but only if:

- The DPI is set correctly (72dpi generally means not set at all, important to be careful with this value)
- The average viewing distance is known
- Printing method is known

Now DPI and size of print have a relationship. Therefore having a target size and pixel size leads implicitly to DPI. In this case you DPI is actually 78 in one direction and 73 in the other. Obviously you don't need the picture to stretch on the entire canvas so you have some leeway on the subject.

Is this enough? Well it is a bit on the lower side of low. But that's all you've got. The rule of thumb is to aim at 150 dpi for the size. So your image is about half whats needed in both directions. But id say 90 could be passable. 72 is a bit pushing it. But might be not so bad.Nowhere near perfect for sure.

Comment: From my experience printing on blankets are made by sublimation. And 50 DPI is enough. The material give it "natural" blur so you cannot see pixels. Of course blurring it on your side is better as you have better control and "shape blur" works the best.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY Like I said it deoends on printing method. Sublimation kindof works with continious tone so its resolution characteristics are different from direct to garment inkjet printing. And more closely resembles a screen than traditional print, while the inkjet and screenprinting really need more resolution due to dithering considerations